# Using FluentMigrator in a Xamarin Portable Class Library

Tags: xamarin, nuget, fluent-migrator

I have created a Xamarin Forms project within VS 2017 Community Edition.  I would like to use FluentMigrator to create a a database for use within the application.

When I attempt to use NuGet PM to install FluentMigrator into the project, I get the following error:

```
Could not install package 'FluentMigrator 1.6.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more 
information, contact the package author.
```

I am guessing it's the fact that my project is using.NETPortable.

Is it possible to use FluentMigrator within a Xamarin PCL?  If so, what needs to be changed in my project configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FluentMigrator does not have any assemblies that are compatible with PCL projects. It contains two lib directories: 35 and 40. These seem to have .NET assemblies for .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0. So you cannot install this into a PCL project.

I would instead see if you can just create a .NET project, say targeting .NET 4.5, and install the FluentMigrator NuGet package into that project and define your migrations there.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I want to be able to run the migrations in a Xamarin app to create an SQLite database on both Android and iOS.  If I create a separate project as you've mentioned, targeting .NET 4.5, I don't think I'll be able to package the code in that project into the Xamarin code.  Am I correct on that?

Comment: Ah I see you want to be able to run the migrations on the mobile device. So no you will not be able to use the fluent migrator unless you can compile it from source either into a PCL or onto each platform. Or look for another NuGet package that works on the platforms you need. Sqlite-net has some [automatic migration](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/wiki/AutomaticMigrations) support built-in.

Comment: I made a few attempts to get the FluentMigrator code to compile into a PCL, but didn't want to spend a ton of time on it.  For now I'll probably try the separate project approach, and create a database file to be installed along with the mobile app; this won't allow me a lot of flexibility if changes need to be made, but I'll have to live with that.  There will potentially be a server side database with the project as well, so using something that is Sqlite specific isn't too appealing, as I wouldn't plan on using that as a server-side DB.